# How to use external display as default

Tags: bios, vga, external-display

When I use my external monitor with my laptop, the external monitor begins to display when the  OS starts to load, unlike the internal monitor in the laptop, which begins to display from the beginning, including the OEM Logo and bios.

It is the same when I connect the monitor to my old laptop or my friend's laptop.

It doesn't matter at first, but recently I go an embedded machine, I want to use the external monitor to setup OS, although the monitor detected a signal, but do not display anything.

The embedded machine is functional because it worked when I use my friend's monitor.

So how do make an external monitor work as the default monitor of a computer, so it can display when booting up like a desktop?

Or there are differences that some monitors can and some can't?

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to do with the way **BIOS** reads your displays and may or may not be posible, for instance in my MultiMonitor setup, I have the HDMI output setup as default, and works fine once the OS loads up, but during bootup, the default is always the VGA monitor. You can check if your **BIOS settings** has any such feature.

Similarly your embedded system needs to be able to display on your external Monitor **without OS driver** support..

edit: [this](http://www.computing.net/answers/hardware/configure-laptop-bios-to-use-external-monitor/85811.html) page seems to tackle the same issue.

Comment: Bios is correct, my new HP and my older T60 thinkpad allows the bios post screen to show on my laptop screen and external monitor (hdmi or vga), once windows starts to load it turns off the laptop display and uses my external which I have set to default in windows. Older bios's do not support this.

Comment: One big problem is the embedded machine works with my friend's monitor without any extra setting but do not work with mine...

Comment: both vga? if different display technologies, that might explain it